# Populate a database with datas from a graphql api

Tags: postgresql, next.js, graphql, apollo, prisma

I'm searching, as the topic name says, to populate a database with datas coming from an already exist graphql [API](https://anilist.gitbook.io/anilist-apiv2-docs/overview/graphql/getting-started).

My project is using **Next.js**, **PostgreSQL**, **Apollo** for **GraphQL** and **Prisma** to connect the whole. I managed to retrieve datas from the API and display these. Now I just want to store these datas in my Postgres database. So you know I'm using the *Client-Side Rendering* and not the other methods (SSR, SSG).

All documentations I found was about creating an API then post to the database which is not my case or documentation about *create* & *createMany* queries but with hardcoded datas. My research doesn't help me to see clear so I come here to find anyone who is willing to guide me. If have a clue I'll appreciate. Thank you =) !

To illustrate here a piece of code :

```
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";

// query to retrieve 3 animes

const QUERY = gql`
  query GetFirstsThree{
    Page(page: 1, perPage: 3) {
      media {
        title {
          userPreferred
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default function AnimList() {
  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(QUERY);
  
  if (loading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }
  if (error) {
    return null;
  }

  const medias = data.Page.media;

  return (
    <div className="mainGrid">
      {medias.map((value) => {
        return (
            <p>{value.title.userPreferred} </p>
        )
      })}
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: To clarify, at what point do you want to store the data in the database? Do you want to store the response from the GraphQL API when the request is made on the client-side?

Comment: I managed to solve my problem the answer is down there =). Thank you for your consideration =D.

Answer (score 0):

Hello for those who have the same issue here is how i resolved my problem.

First I have created a async function to post my Anime.

```
async function savedAnime(anime){
  const res = await fetch('api/anime', {
    method: 'Post',
    body: JSON.stringify(anime),
  });
if(!res.ok){
  throw new Error('Something went wrong');
}
  return await  res.json();
}
```

Then I added a submit input, which on its onClick event will map the medias the same way I did to display the anime's title, but here to store the datas in the database.
After, I create a variable with my datas that I want to store. Finally, I call the function I've created before to post my Anime, on which I pass the variable.

And that pretty much all.

```
      <input type="submit" value="Save Animes" onClick={ async () => {
        try{
        medias.map(async (value) => {
          const anime = {
            title: value.title.userPreferred,
            coverImage: value.coverImage.medium,
          };
          console.log(anime);
          savedAnime(anime); 
        })
        } catch(err){
          console.error(err);
        }
      }}/>
```